# Positioning div elements horizontally, not vertically

Tags: css, layout, html, positioning

Im designing a navigation bar; and tab links in it are made by CSS shapes. For this I use alot of `position: absolute` on child elements, and I have parent containers set to `position: relative`. I also set a hard height and plenty width for them, and it will not work. Not even with using `overflow: ..`. My tab boxes positions vertically no matter what.

I have no clue at this point.

Divs inside "navBox" class div have `position: absolute`.

Click [here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/qLKg7/1/) for HTML and CSS code, and watch output results.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you set up a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are you using float:left; somewhere or display:inline-block; you need to show some css

Comment: Posted code and result here http://jsfiddle.net/qLKg7/1/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need your `.navBox` class to `display: inline-block`. Naturally the `div` element is set to display block which gives the element by default a width of 100%. Also, your list items to `float: left` because by default a list is displayed vertically, floating left allows you to display the list horizontal

updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qLKg7/4/

Answer (score 7):

CSS: `display: inline` or `display:inline-block`.